# Installing django apps without pip install

Tags: python, django, hosting, shared-hosting

What is the best way of installing django apps and python packages without using pip?

I will be hosting my site on hostgator.com and will not be able to install python packages using pip because I won't have access to the root account.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know about [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)? I don't have any experience with hostgator.com but virtualenv is designed to allow you to create virtual python environments to install basically any Python package you want on a system where you don't have root access.

You just 1) create a virtual environment, 2) activate it, 3) use pip to install what you need.

After you've done that, each time you want to run Python software that uses the packages you've installed, just activate the environment and launch your Python script or application. (You can have more than one virtual environment if you need to install different packages, or different versions of packages. All are kept isolated from each other, and from the system-level Python and its site-packages.)

It's an essential Python tool, and pretty well explained at the above link. Here's a [link](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/) to a tutorial that many people find useful.

Comment: Hostgator doesn't seem to have virtualenv installed on their servers... And then how would I tell my django app to use the virtualenv?

Comment: Download virtualenv.py anywhere in or under your home directory and run it from there. You can do anything you want in or under your home directory. At the above link, see the part that says _if you have no Python package manager available at all, you can just grab the single file virtualenv.py and run it with python virtualenv.py._

Comment: Now that I have virtualenv... how do I get my django project to use this virtualenv?

Comment: Sorry. I know nothing about hostgator.com. You'll have to ask their tech support.

Comment: First google hit on "django virtualenv": http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290325/python-virtualenv-quickstart-django  Also has a link to running within `mod_wsgi`.